# jQuery get second class and remove a class

Tags: jquery

Hy there,

i have posts sorted by their year. By default they are all hidden (they get the .js class which hides the element). So now it looks like this:

```
<div class="press-wrapper">
 <div class="post-entry post-2011 js">...</div>
 <div class="post-entry post-2011 js">...</div>
 <div class="post-entry post-2010 js">...</div>
 <div class="post-entry post-2010 js">...</div>
 <div class="post-entry post-2009 js">...</div>
 <div class="post-entry post-2009 js">...</div>
 <div class="post-entry post-2008 js">...</div>
</div>
```

I want documentReady load all items with the newest date, so it should look like:

```
<div class="press-wrapper">
 <div class="post-entry post-2011">...</div>
 <div class="post-entry post-2011">...</div>
 <div class="post-entry post-2010 js">...</div>
 <div class="post-entry post-2010 js">...</div>
 <div class="post-entry post-2009 js">...</div>
 <div class="post-entry post-2009 js">...</div>
 <div class="post-entry post-2008 js">...</div>
</div>
```

So i have a function that gets the first post class:

```
var pressClass = $('.press-wrapper div:first').attr('class').split(' ')[1];
```

WHen i now try to remove the ".js" nothing happends:

```
$(pressClass).removeClass('js');
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You have to prefix the selector using a dot.

Comment: @RobW not when calling `.removeClass()`

Comment: @Pointy At the selector: `$('.' + pressClass)`. The class attribute contains a *whitespace-separated* list of class names. Class selectors have to be prefixed by a dot.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying.  Yes I agree - I didn't correctly understand what the OP was trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks people,

in the end i came up with:

```
var pressClass = $('.press-wrapper div:first').attr('class').split(' ')[1];
$("." + pressClass).removeClass('js');
```

Really simple. All i want is to get the latest post year (that´s automaticly on top) and than just get all other entries with the same year.

That worked!!!

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

*You were missing the dot that indicates a class*

```
$("." + pressClass).removeClass('js');
```

**But I don't know if you can depend on the class names being in the correct order every time!**

I would suggest instead building the string based on something else like this depending on year needs:

```
var year = new Date().getFullYear()
var className = "post-" + year
$("." + className).removeClass('js')
```

If you're worried that the year won't exist try this:

```
var year = new Date().getFullYear()
for (var i = year; i < year - 10; i--) {
    if ($(".post-" + i).length) break;
}
$(".post-" + i).removeClass('js')
```

Comment: What if there are no post for the current year? You still have to remove the class from the latest post.

Comment: Well, you have two options. 1) Use a loop like this ``for (var i = year; i < year - 10; i--) if ($("post-" + i).length) break;`` now the variable ``i`` will contain the first year that is available. 2) You could use whatever you were using to generate the years in the list on the server-side to put it in some JavaScript that could look like this ``var firstYear = <?= $year ?>;``

Answer (score 0):

*edit* — I think I may have misunderstood the question, but here's stuff anyway:

---

You're trying to wrap the string you get from that first expression up as a jQuery object, and that doesn't make sense.

Really, you should think of the "class" attribute as a vector; it's pretty fragile to rely on the order of class elements, especially when you're using a library like jQuery.  If you want to remove the "js" class, remove it like this:

```
$('.press-wrapper div:first').removeClass('js');
```

If you only want to remove it when the element has some *other* class, you can test for it:

```
var $firstDiv = $('.press-wrapper div:first');
if ($firstDiv.hasClass('post-2010'))
  $firstDiv.removeClass('js');
```

Or whatever, as appropriate to your needs.

Comment: I want to remove the class with the latest date. So next year, my sorting gets a post-2012 and than this should be the one that is visible...

Comment: @user1065862 well I'm not sure that using classes is the easiest way to do this. It would be easier if you had a "data-year" attribute with the year value all by itself. Then you could more easily sort/filter the elements.

Comment: True, i will think of it in the next project... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`var pressClass = $('.press-wrapper div:first').attr('class').split(' ')[1];` will give you a string 'post-2011`. So you prefix it with`.` to make a class selector. Try this.

```
$("." + pressClass).removeClass('js');
```

You should not depend on the class sequence to be like that.

```
var pressClass = $('.press-wrapper div:first').attr('class').split(' ');
if(pressClass.lenght > 0){
   $.each(pressClass, function(i, class){
       if(class.indexOf('post-') != -1){
          preseClass = class;
          return false;
       }
   }
}
```

Then use `pressClass` and remove the class

```
$("." + pressClass).removeClass('js');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **[selector](http://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=jquery%20selector&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/&ei=wcwiT_iNIejj4QSmtaDXCA&usg=AFQjCNFP7N8UvHOYUWpwOT49rwZKDbzHFA&cad=rja)** is wrong.

```
$('.press-wrapper div:first').removeClass('js');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var pressClass = $('.press-wrapper div:first');
$(pressClass).removeClass('js');
```

take out the attr you already know what you're wanting to remove. Just define the div you want to remove it from.

Comment: `pressClass` is already a jQuery object, so there's no reason to wrap it in another jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

What about `$('.post-entry:first-child').removeClass('js');`